How do I set an C# array to a cell value using Excel Interop, so that the cell "spills"
I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to open a Workbook. I then find the Worksheet that I need, and find a named cell in the Worksheet. I want to be able to set the value of the cell to an array, so that those values "spill" (an Excel term).
If I set the value of the cell in Excel by hand like this
={1;2;3}
I will get a spill where the first cell has 1, then the one below it has 2, and then 3 below that. Same for
={"foo";"bar";"fizz"}
I'd like to have a function in C# that can take in a dynamic array, and write that to the cell. I could use a StringBuilder to concat all the values and then set the formula of the cell. But if the dynamic array is strings then I have to worry about the quotes.
Is there a simpler way to achieve the desired behavior? Here is what I have so far. This method is one for a class that handles the opening of the Excel file. Its also part of an AutoCAD plugin, which is the transaction object, but thats not really important.

public void testMethod3(Transaction tr)//AutoCAD object
{
    var pages = Workbook.Worksheets.Cast<Worksheet>()
        .Where(sheet => sheet.Name.Contains("Export"))
        .ToList();

    if (pages.Count != 1) return;

    if (!Save)
    {
        pages.ForEach(p =>
        {
            p.Columns.ClearFormats();
            p.Rows.ClearFormats();
        });
    }

    dynamic range = pages[0]?.Names?.Item("LoopRoom")?.RefersToRange?.Cells;

    List<MyObject> myObjects = //data objects with string property RoomName

    object[,] data = new object[myObjects.Count+1,1];

    for (int i = 0; i < loops.Count; i++)
    {
        data[i, 0] = myObjects[i].RoomName;
    }

    


    range.Value2 = data;

}


Edit 0:
In reply to @rotabor
I had to change the code slightly but it did work. Though the dates showed up as "#####" in excel until I clicked into and out of the cell. Here is the modified code.
public void testMethod4(string path)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL; Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oWB; Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
    try
    {
        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        {
            Visible = false
        };
        //oXL.Visible = true;
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path);
        oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
        oSheet.Range["A1:B2"].Value = new object[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, null } };
        var itm = new object[] { 1, "Hello, World!", DateTime.Now };
        oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[4, 1], oSheet.Cells[4, itm.Length]].Value = itm;

        dynamic range = oSheet.Names.Item("SORange").RefersToRange.Cells;
        itm = new object[] { 2, "Hello, StackOverflow!", DateTime.Now };
        range.Value = itm;

        oWB.Save();
        oWB.Close(false);
        oXL.Quit();
    }
    catch (Exception theException)
    {
        String errorMessage;
        errorMessage = "Error: ";
        errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Message);
        errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, " Line: ");
        errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Source);
        
    }
}

The problem is the "range" that I want to use is a single cell, and within that cell I want to put an array, which will spill into other cells below.


Just assign the value array like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38542748/visual-c-sharp-setting-multiple-cells-at-once-with-excel-interop?

Unfortunatly that did not work. If I change from range.Value2 to range.Value the value of the cell is only the first value in the array. I also tried using LINQ and .Select(m => m.RoomName).ToArray() instead of the array from the original post. But not luck.

You can use .Offset() to locate the bottom right corner, and .WorkSheet.Range() to combine them into a rectangle. Then assign a 2d array, as per the linked answer.

First of all, there is the working code below:
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms; 
//csc /r:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ADDINS\PowerPivot Excel Add-in\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" excel.cs
namespace TestConsoleApp {
    class Program {
       static void Main() {
            Excel.Application oXL; Excel.Workbook oWB; Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
            try {
                oXL = new Excel.Application();
                oXL.Visible = true;
                oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\ashatikhin\\Documents\\My Projects\\Stackoverflow\\Book333.xlsx");
                oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
                oSheet.Range["A1:B2"].Value = new object[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, null } };
                var itm = new object[] { 1, "Hello, World!", DateTime.Now };
                oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[4, 1], oSheet.Cells[4, itm.Length]).Value = itm;
                dynamic range = oWB.Names.Item("SORange").RefersToRange.Cells;
                itm = new object[] { 2, "Hello, StackOverflow!", DateTime.Now };
                range.Value = itm;
                range = oWB.Names.Item("StringsOnly").RefersToRange.Cells;
                var sqitm = new object[,] { { "One", "Two" }, { "Three", "Four" } };
                range.Value = sqitm;
                var sa = new string[] { "June", "July", "August" };
                range = oSheet.Range["A8"];
                range.Formula2 = "={\"" + string.Join("\";\"", sa) + "\"}";
                oWB.Save();
                oWB.Close(false);
                oXL.Quit();
            }
            catch( Exception theException ) 
            {
                String errorMessage;
                errorMessage = "Error: ";
                errorMessage = String.Concat( errorMessage, theException.Message );
                errorMessage = String.Concat( errorMessage, " Line: " );
                errorMessage = String.Concat( errorMessage, theException.Source );
                MessageBox.Show( errorMessage, "Error" );
            }
        }
    }
}



You need to use dynamic type and Formula2 property to set the formula with dynamic arrays.
Can you test it and clarify your expectations and what is wrong?
P. S.
It can be the easiest way for you:
itm = new object[] { 2, "Hello, StackOverflow!", DateTime.Now };
oSheet.Range["A12"].Resize[1, itm.Length].Value = itm;


I edited the post to reply, before seeing edits. I'll need to test the "new" code you've provided

I now see that the code you've added using months is what I have created as well. I was hoping there might be a more elegant way as this method means when I feed a dynamic array into my function I'll have to add quotes to strings. But if thats what needs to happen then so be it

Traditionally the string constant is defined using double quotes, and there is no way to bypass these.

But putting the dynamic array formula with constant values into a cell has no sense in your task. You need to assign the array to the range of cells, and you don't need to manipulate with quotes following this way.

My problem is that I wanted to have a function that can take a dynamic array of either numbers, or string, and have one process that works for both. But to create the formula using strings as shown requires quote marks around strings, but does not for numbers. Its not the end of the world, but it does add some complexity to the code that I hoped to avoid.
